# Python: Looking for way to broadcast large data to clients

Tags: python, sockets, network-programming, broadcast

I want send a large pickle dump to several clients using broadcasting, however, it turns out that the data I'm trying to send is too large to be sent over the UDP protocol.

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)

serial_data = pickle.dumps(data)
print(sys.getsizeof(serial_data))
s.sendto(serial_data, ('<broadcast>', 37020))
```

Splitting wont help since i dont want the received data to be in bytes.

I managed to send the data sequentially to my clients using a TCP connection, but as a next step, i need broadcasting to be done for my experiment. Are there any other protocols that exist which may help resolve this issue?

Comment: “Splitting wont help since i dont want the received data to be in bytes”. All data is sent as bytes. What do you mean here?

Comment: Im not aware of a way to deserialize the data without changing the format to bytes

Comment: `pickle.dumps` returns `bytes` objects so it is already bytes.  Split it up, send it, put it back together, and `pickle.loads` the result.  UDP is unreliable, however, so you'll need to number the packets, request any missing ones, and order them for reassembly.  Example from a quick google search: https://github.com/gistrec/File-Broadcaster

Comment: Example isn't Python but has a nice description of the protocol involved.